# Have trouble making my drop down menu appear when going into mobile mode

Tags: html, css, nav

Whenever I click on the dropdown bar nothing appears and I see a notification that says javascript: void(0). I tried taking that out of the code and it still does not do anything.

```js
function dropdownMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive"
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav"
  }
}
```

```css
nav,
header,
footer {
  display: block;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px;
  list-style-type: none;
  min-height: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: black;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon {
  display: none;
}


/*########Mobile*/

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1)) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon {
    display: block;
    float: right;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signin">Sign In</a></li>
    <li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dropdownMenu">&#9776;</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Paste your code here, not images. It makes it very hard for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add braces() to your element onclick event call i.e `onclick="dropdownMenu()"`

```js
function dropdownMenu(){
        var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
        if(x.className === "topnav"){
            x.className += " responsive"
        }else{
            x.className= "topnav"
        }
    }
```

```css
nav,
header,
footer{
    display: block;
}



nav{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul{
    background-color: floralwhite;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;

}
 ul.topnav li a{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
     min-height: 16px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 25px;
     text-decoration: none;

}
ul.topnav li a:hover{
    background-color: aqua;
    color: black;

}
ul.topnav li.topnav-right{
    float: right;
}
ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon{
    display: none;
}
/*########Mobile*/

@media screen and (max-width: 680px){
    ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1)){
        display: none;
    }
    ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon{
        display:block;
        float:right;
    }

ul.topnav.responsive{
    position: relative;
}

    ul.topnav.responsive li{
        display:inline;
        float:none;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a{
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to My Website</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

<body>
    <nav>
    <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signin">Sign In</a></li>
        <li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dropdownMenu()">&#9776;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess following code will meet your requirement.

**custom.Js**

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a class="topnav-right" href="#">Sign Up</a>
  <a class="topnav-right" href="#">Sign In</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a.topnav-right{
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

[you can find the detail here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)